# Emoji as question mark sending an email

Tags: html-email, emoji

sending an email as HTML some emoji are displayed as questions mark -> ???? and some not.

```
<b>Lancio del programma di affiliazione &#128512;</b>
```

Example1

[image: Example1]

Example where in the same email the emoji isn't displayed as questions mark.

```
<b>Iscriviti e se hai bisogno di maggiori informazioni contattaci senza esitazione! &#9203;</b>
```

Example2

[image: Example2]

Comment: what are viewing the emails in? Chances are the font it's using is not completely up to date with all emoji.

Comment: @phuzi I have viewed it in outlook web, outlook app and in gmail. Always same problem. Font? What do you mean, font-family? I'm using Arial

Comment: What browser are you using for gmail and outlook web?

Comment: @phuzi Firefox, but the same in Chrome

Comment: Was a database involved?